# Referencing a custom code analysis rule library using a ruleset file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

There is not much easy-to-find information regarding custom code analysis rules for Visual Studio 2010. Although this is what I have found in regards to my question...

In the [sample library on CodePlex](http://bit.ly/CSCustomCodeAnalysisRule) it is shown how to deploy a custom code analysis rule library, which uses a Setup Project to dump the library's DLL into **Program Files Folder -> Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 -> Team Tools -> Static Analysis Tools -> FxCop -> Rules**.

Moreover, a very useful how-to [blog post by Duke Kamstra](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx) also suggests to copy the library's dll into **%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules**.

My preference is to avoid sticking DLLs in such a global location. I wanted to have the DLL relative to my Visual Studio solutions, so that when I update the DLL with some custom code analysis rule changes then I need not take an extra step to keep dependencies of the DLL up-to-date.

One perfect solution for me would be to have my custom ***.ruleset** file be aware of the relative path to the DLL, but I've been unsuccessful in doing so.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

In your .ruleset file, you should be able to add relative paths to the custom rule DLLs.  e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="Sample" Description="Sample ruleset" ToolsVersion="10.0">
  <RuleHintPaths>
    <Path>..\Tools\FxCop\SomeRules.dll</Path>
    <Path>..\Tools\FxCop\SomeOtherRules.dll</Path>
  </RuleHintPaths>
  ...
</RuleSet>
```

Comment: Do you happen to know what the path is relative to?  Is it relative to the location of the .ruleset file?

Comment: The paths are relative to the project.

Answer (score 3):

I found even the correct project-relative relative path (provided as [Nicole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6443661/2030644)) to my custom rules assembly did not cause my rules to appear in the ruleset editor, while an absolute path to the same assembly did make the rules show up.  When I enabled the rules and then changed the path back to a relative path, the rules remain in the editor and are run during source analysis.  If I uncheck the rules with a relative path specified, the rules disappear - this seems like a bug in the rules editor.

So, if your rules do not seem to appear when specifying a relative path, try using an absolute one, enabling the rules, and then switching back to a relative path (relative to the project location per @Raithlin).

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to also affect VS 2013. I've found that manually entering the relative path to a rules assembly **and** the rules from that assembly will result in those rules appearing when I open the ruleset using Visual Studio's ruleset designer UI. The rules will also be ran.

So an operational **CustomRules.ruleset** could look like this, where `SR1000` is a rule from *SomeRules.dll* and `SOR1000` is from *SomeOtherRules.dll*. Note that the tools version is **12.0** for Visual Studio 2013.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="Sample" Description="Sample ruleset" ToolsVersion="12.0">
  <RuleHintPaths>
    <Path>..\Tools\FxCop\SomeRules.dll</Path>
    <Path>..\Tools\FxCop\SomeOtherRules.dll</Path>
  </RuleHintPaths>
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.Analyzers.ManagedCodeAnalysis" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.Rules.Managed">
    <Rule Id="SR1000" Action="Error" />
    <Rule Id="SOR1000" Action="Warning" />
    <!-- etc. -->
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

Note that you can easily include standard Microsoft rules by adding includes like this to `RuleSet`:

```
<Include Path="minimumrecommendedrules.ruleset" Action="Default" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio C# 2015 with Update 2. My custom rules do not show up in the ruleset editor of Visual Studio 2015. However when i run the CodeAnalysis, violations appear if there are any. My RuleHintPath looks like this and is relative to the location of the ruleset file:

```
<RuleHintPaths>
  <Path>..\Rules</Path>
</RuleHintPaths>
```

So because the violations are found, it is a fact that the rule DLLs are found by the given relative path. Why the rules do not show up within the ruleset editor is the question. That's why i assume a bug of the editor.